# Heatmap.js with leaflet. Max Value not working as expected

Tags: javascript, leaflet, heatmap

I have a leaflet map with a [heatmap](https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-heatmap-leaflet.html). Everything is working perfectly except for the max value of the heatmap.

So let's say I have 30 points with a value going from 4 to 15

```
{'lat':x,'lng':y,'value':5},{'lat':x,'lng':y,'value':10}...etc
```

And my max is 15. So that would mean that my point with value 15 would be the red point right?

```
var heatData = {
   max: maxNumber,
   data: heatPoints
}
```

That works as expected.

However, if I change my max to 1000 I would expect all my points to go towards the blue color since no point is close to 1000.

That doesn't work as expected. **Here is a demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/pvanb/rgb4dagp/

Try changing the max value and you'll see the heatmap stays the same.

Is this a bug or is there something I'm not doing correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I figured it out myself. 
You have to set `useLocalExtrema` to `false` in the config:

```
var cfg = {           
                "radius": 0.2,
                "maxOpacity": .8, 
                "scaleRadius": true, 
                "useLocalExtrema": false,
                latField: 'lat',
                lngField: 'lng',
                valueField: 'count'
};
```